# Only suggest one tier from a badge family at a time

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page, badge-progress

Could we limit the badge suggestions to the first tier of badges? Somewhat like with tag badges.

I ask as this is what my top suggested badges looks like:

[image: Multiple tiers of the same badges family]

Both legendary and epic, and illuminator and refiner are different tiers from the same family. In short, if I'm going for the gold version I'll hit the silver version first. It seems like a waste of space for that reason.

Comment: Do you mean only one tier *within any given family*, or only one tier *at all* (e.g. no gold until you've got all the silvers)?  I think you mean the former, but your title sounds like you mean the latter and that might be causing downvotes.

Comment: Still not enough free hand circles

Comment: @DnrDevil that do it for you?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you're going to hit the silver badge on the way to the gold, but that's separate from how someone may want to track progress. I can see how someone may want to skip straight to Legendary in the tracker, yet someone else would go in order and pick Epic first.

<sub>(I realize the same applies to tag badges, but my personal preference would be to, if we're going to do anything at all, make tag badge tracking work more like regular badge tracking rather than the other way around.)</sub>

Comment: I appreciate your view point,  thanks for sharing.

Comment: Should this be [tag:status-declined]?